# ffmpeg: Considers AVPixelFormat as Int?

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

I would like to use a function `ff_load_image`.

**program.c**

```
#include "../ffmpeg/libavfilter/lavfutils.h"

int main ()
{
  uint8_t* data;

  int linesize, width, height, log_ctx;

  int i = ff_load_image(&data, &linesize, &width, &height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, "blue.jpg", &log_ctx);
}
```

This compiles, but gives a warning.

```
program.c: In function 'main':
program.c:11: warning: passing argument 5 of 'ff_load_image' makes pointer from integer without a cast
../ffmpeg/libavfilter/lavfutils.h:39: note: expected 'enum AVPixelFormat *' but argument is of type 'int'
```

When I run the program, it segment faults. I can't think of any other way to specify a pixel format. Why would ffmpeg think `AV_PIX_FMT_RGB8` is an integer? It's obviously an `AVPixelFormat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ff_load_image()`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/1.1/lavfutils_8c.html) expects an `enum AVPixelFormat *`. `ffmpeg` thought it an integer because it's an `enum` element of [`AVPixelFormat`](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/pixfmt_8h.html). And, [in `C`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp6m.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc03ec.htm), enumeration constants have type `int`.

You should use:

```
enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24;
int i = ff_load_image(&data, &linesize, &width, &height
                           , &pix_fmt, "blue.jpg", &log_ctx);
```

Comment: You cannot use the `&` operator on `AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24`.

Comment: And re: "ffmpeg thought it an integer probably because it's an enum element of AVPixelFormat.", enumeration constants have type `int` in C.